# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'students.urls.py'; 'students.urls' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

i am just a beginner in python learning from tutorials i can't just run the server, i followed the same steps mentioned in that tutorial but its showing me this error, i searched for some possible answers on stack overflow but couldn't find any answer that could resolve my issue, hopeless what to do with this,

my directory structure is as
[image]

in python console in pycharm its showing me this error

> Error:Cannot run program "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\webProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\mydjangoproject"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

in pycharm terminal its showing me this error

```
>  res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\mydjangoproject\mydjangoproject\urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    path('mydjangoproject', include('students.urls.py')),
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1001, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'students.urls.py'; 'students.urls' is not a package
```

Comment: Just a guess: `include('students.urls.py')` should be `include('students.urls')`. You shouldn't add the file extension.

Comment: @Matthias thankyou so much hahahah that worked, seriously i couldn't sort that thing out.

Comment: Just a general rule, just so ya know, anytime you are importing / including / doing a **from**, you always leave off the py

Answer (score 4):

your issue is related to mydjangoproject.urls.py file
probably your code is
`include('students.urls.py')`
the correct one is :
`include('students.urls')`